# Add multiple conditions in match query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I need multiple device in an OR condition for the below query. As of now, only one device "FX16-Non-Coded-Sim3.LT2" is present. How can I add multiple devices (e.g. FX16-Non-Coded-Sim4.LT2, FX16-Non-Coded-Sim5.LT2) in this elastic search query where search will give result even if 1 device is present i.e OR condition for the list of devices present

[image]

Comment: Please remove the screenshot and add the query in quote. `In that way, others can find it.` You can use **should** query that will add the **OR** logic. I'm adding the answer below

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bool should](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query for that.

```
POST _search
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "term" : { "user.id" : "kimchy" }  <-- **AND** -affect score
      },
      "filter": {
        "term" : { "tags" : "production" } <-- **AND** -doesn't affect score + caching the results
      },
      "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
          "age" : { "gte" : 10, "lte" : 20 } <-- **AND** -doesn't affect score
        }
      },
      "should" : [
        { "term" : { "tags" : "env1" } }, <-- **OR** "1"
        { "term" : { "tags" : "deployed" } } <-- **OR** "2"
      ],
      "minimum_should_match" : 1,  <-- There is a OR condition between "1" and "2" and at least one of them should match. 
      "boost" : 1.0
    }
  }
}
```